# Write files uploaded from user into php script to network drive

Tags: php, iis, networking, save

I have a php script that a user uploads a pdf to.

The software lives in

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fundDocs
```

And the pdfs get saved to

```
/pdf    # C:\inetpub\
```

How would I change it so that the file gets saved to the network drive

```
O:\pdf
```

This is the code to write the pdf

```
copy($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "pdf/".$fullFileName);
```

Comment: code for writing pdf's added

Comment: So changing the second argument to the `copy()` function doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
copy($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "O:\pdf/".$fullFileName);
```

Just make sure that the account under which the PHP process is running has access to the network drive, and permission to write files to that folder.